# Display userform if cell is double clicked and it is locked

Tags: excel, vba

I know that I can disable double click by:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

However the problem is that I want to enable it for unlocked cells so user will be able to double click the cells that are unlocked.

How  to make Cancel command active only for locked cells? Something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If ActiveCell.Locked = True Then
    Cancel = True
    NoNoNo.Show (vbmodeless)
    Else

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did it work ?? your second code. I think all you are missing is a `End If` after your userform Show

Comment: Why would you use `ActiveCell` instead of `Target`?

Comment: Well since OP is double clicking, `Target` and `ActiveCell` will be the same.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! I would say it works in my case quite well. However If I have unlocked and locked cells on the same sheet this solution does not work if I double click locked cells. On double clicking it just drops the pointer to unlocked cells.

Comment: Does the sheet protection allow for selection of locked cells or not? If you can't select a locked cell, then you can't double click it.

Comment: No. locked cells can't be selected. That is true. My logical thinking was offline. 
I think that's enough for this time. I can live with the solution provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Target.Locked = True Then
        Cancel = True
    Else
    NoNoNo.Show (vbModeless)
    End If

End Sub
```

All you are missing is `End If` and as `K.Davis` pointed out you should use `Target` instead of `Activecell`